# `expire max` together with `rewrite` and `break`

Tags: nginx

I am a beginner in the Nginx configuration. I am trying to configure rewriting request from `/api` subdirectory to correct path using this configuration:

```
location ~ ^/api/ {
  root $backend_folder;
  rewrite  ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Everything work as I expect: I have a jpg file in directory `$backend_folder/media/image.jpg` and a URL `http://example.com/api/media/image.jpg` works. But when I've added cache configuration:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|svg)$ { access_log off; expires max; }
```

I've started getting 404 on this URL.

The whole configuration after change looks like:

```
...
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|svg)$ { access_log off; expires max; }
...
location ~ ^/api/ {
  root $backend_folder;
  rewrite  ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I wonder why this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx chooses one location to process a request. The two locations in your configuration are mutually exclusive. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

You might consider nesting the locations, or using a map to set the expires directive.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default                                                  off;
    ~\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt|svg)($|\?)  max;
}
expires $expires;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.